# HTML: How to get rid of overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I am working on a chart using ChartJS, and I have a problem with it that I need to solve.

At the bottom, the labels of the X-Axis are all overlapping, and I don't know how to get rid of that. I want it to show as many as possible without overlapping. I also want it to be responsive, so if I resize it, it will add or remove the number of labels to meet with my expectation.

Thanks for any help in advance!

```js
$(function() {

  //get the line chart canvas
  var ctx = $("#line-chartcanvas");

  //line chart data
  var data = {
    labels: ["match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5", "match1", "match2", "match3", "match4", "match5"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "TeamA Score",
        data: [10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40, 10, 50, 25, 70, 40],
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        borderColor: "lightblue",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        radius: 5
      },
      {
        label: "TeamB Score",
        data: [20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50, 20, 35, 40, 60, 50],
        backgroundColor: "green",
        borderColor: "lightgreen",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        radius: 5
      }
    ]
  };

  //options
  var options = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      position: "top",
      text: "Line Graph",
      fontSize: 18,
      fontColor: "#111"
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "bottom",
      labels: {
        fontColor: "#333",
        fontSize: 16
      }
    },
    animation: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 90,
          autoSkip: false
        }
      }]
    },
    responsive: true
  };

  //create Chart class object
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: data,
    options: options
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- javascript -->
<script src="https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/download/v2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>


<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="line-chartcanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: `autoSkip: true` or change canvas `width`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the limit dynamically, change the maxTicksLimit value, then call update on the chart.  To keep access to the generated chart, I used a closure, but a global variable would work as well.

Note that the xAxes is an array.

```
(function(theChart){
  $("#demo").click(function() {
    theChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.maxTicksLimit = 5;
    theChart.update();
  });
}(chart));
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2o58gbe/3/)

The example is changing on a click, but the same would work on any other trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It may not make complete sense with the data in your sample, but for the specific question:

```
    ticks: {
      maxTicksLimit: 10,
      autoSkip: true
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/microMerlin/x2o58gbe/1/

See http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html and http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration

Comment: That helps, but I actually want it to dynamically change based on the screen size. If I view this on my computer it may look fine, but on my phone it is overlapping again.

Comment: Then you will need to add a function that triggers on resize, calculates a new limit, and calls update on the chart.

Comment: How do I edit the limit? I have tried this: `options.scales.xAxes.ticks.maxTicksLimit = newNumber;`  but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong there?